# Unsubscribe is giving error in Angular application?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I'm Subscribing for a REST call

```
this.empObs0 = this.fetchData.getEmployeeInfoToUpdate(JSON.parse(this.empName0)).subscribe(
  data0 => {
    this.emp_DBRows0 = <EmpUpdateModel[]> data0;
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

**FetchDataService.ts**

```
// gets the employee information to update the employee info
getEmployeeInfoToUpdate(jsonArray: JSON): Observable<EmpUpdateModel[]> {
  console.log('GET getEmployeeInfoToUpdate');
  this.dataGS =  this.http.post<Observable<EmpUpdateModel[]>>('/api/getEmployeeInfoToUpdate', jsonArray);
  return this.dataGS;
}
```

I want to destroy this in `ngOnDestroy()`

```
// Destroying the component.
ngOnDestroy() {
  console.log('Destroy called');
  this.empObs0.unsubscribe();
}
```

But while destroying I'm getting below error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsuscribe' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsuscribe' of undefined
    at UpdateTeamRosterComponent.push../src/app/components/update-team-roster/update-team-roster.component.ts.UpdateTeamRosterComponent.ngOnDestroy (update-team-roster.component.ts:176)
    at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:18943)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:18911)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:18901)
    at destroyView (core.js:19963)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:20722)
    at Object.debugDestroyView [as destroyView] (core.js:20406)
    at ViewRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.destroy (core.js:18232)
    at ComponentRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentRef_.destroy (core.js:18068)
    at RouterOutlet.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.RouterOutlet.deactivate (router.js:4858)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:14134)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
```

Help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are storing the **`Observable`** in a variable that means you need to `unsubscribe` it but if you have any `error` while storing it, then the variable value will be **`undefined`**. So check for `undefined` first then `unsubscribe` it

```
// Destroying the component.

ngOnDestroy() {
  if(this. empObs0) 
    this.empObs0.unsuscribe();
}
```

If you have more observables then it will be better practice to do it in way that @sachila suggested

Comment: yup your suggestion helped me!!

Answer (score 1):

As a  best practice what u can do is create a subscription array and push the subscriptions to that array. Then on the destroy cycle unsubscribe to it using a loop

```
subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];


this.subscriptions.push(this.fetchData.getEmployeeInfoToUpdate(JSON.parse(this.empName0)).subscribe(
  data0 => {
    this.emp_DBRows0 = <EmpUpdateModel[]> data0;
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
));

 ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscriptions.forEach(subscription => {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for showing a better way to unsubscribing the Observables